# Setting Property of View Model to Knockout Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Using MVC 4, I am trying to send a viewmodel back to the controller with a value that was populated using Knockout in the javascript part section of my view.

Psuedocode:

```
var ProgramOptionsVm = function() {
   self = this;
   self.AvailableOptions is populated (IList<RegistrationOption>)
}
```

I want to set AvailableOptions equal to field of viewmodel. Something like:

```
Model.AvailableOptions = ProgramOptionsVm.AvailableOptions
```

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set `Model.AvailableOptions` directly with your Knockout view model. The two things exist in different scopes: the former is server-side, while the latter is client-side. You would have to POST the data back to another controller action.